# Excel VBA keeps turning cells black

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I have written code so if the cell value is more than 0.10 it turns yellow. If not, it should stay white. Instead of staying white, the cell turns black. I can't figure out why it is doing this.

```
Sub moreThan10Percent()
For nRow = 2 To 1937
    For nColumn = 6 To 6
        If Cells(nRow, nColumn) >= 0.1 Then
            Cells(nRow, nColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
            Cells(nRow, nColumn).Interior.Color = 1
        End If
    Next nColumn
Next nRow
```

End Sub

Comment: Change your if to simply `If Cells(nRow, nColumn) >= 0.1 Then             Cells(nRow, nColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 6` Also, you could easily do this with conditional formating. Is that not an option in your case?

Comment: You don't want it to *'stay white'*. You want to remove all fill color. Instead of `Cells(nRow, nColumn).Interior.Color = 1` use `Cells(nRow, nColumn).Interior.PATTERN = xlNone`.

Comment: Fernando - I do have that option, but I have to redownload multiple excel sheets quite often. So I was hoping to use VBA to speed that up.

Comment: To me this worked when trying to reset the bgcolor from an event:
`oEvent.CellBackColor = -1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I put the bulk of your checker into a separate sub with parameters. The first sub is the one with the name you chose, and the others are examples of different ways to refer to the cells you want to check. Following that is the main sub that loops through the cells and does the checking, but without nested for-next loops. The last sub is an extension of the conversation, and it creates a reference worksheet with a table of all the Excel indexed colors.

The three parameters are: 1) Range of cells to check, 2) Threshold of the check, and 3) Color to change the cell to.

The reason for the breakout into a sub with parameters is that I was also trying to make this work from the Worksheet_Change and Workbook_SheetChange events. This can be a wonderful extension of the regular Conditional Formatting on the Excel UI, but without constraint of that wonky set of controls. You can make Excel do anything you within its power when someone types a certain value in a certain cell or range of cells.

But my way of implementing those events this way requires the use of the Intersect() function, and I'm getting some weird errors that I don't recall getting before. I'll work them out and report back with the completed code.

```
Sub moreThan10Percent()
    checkValues Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(1937, 6)), 0.1, 3
End Sub

Sub moreWays1()
    checkValues Range("F2:F1937"), 0.1, 6
End Sub

Sub moreWays2()
    checkValues Intersect(Range("F:F"), Range("2:1937")), 0.1, 6
End Sub

Sub moreWays3()
    checkValues Intersect(Columns(6).EntireColumn, Range(Rows(2).EntireRow, Rows(1937).EntireRow)), 0.1, 6
End Sub

Sub moreWays4()
    checkValues Intersect(Columns(6).EntireColumn, Range(Rows(2), Rows(1937).EntireRow)), 0.1, 6
End Sub

Sub checkValues(targetRange As Range, targetThreshold As Single, targetColor As Long)
    Dim targetCell As Range
    For Each targetCell In targetRange
        With targetCell
            If .value >= targetThreshold Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = targetColor
            Else
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub generateTableOfExcelColorIndexes()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "COLORS"
    i = 0
    For Each cell In Range("A1:H7")
        i = i + 1
        With cell
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .value = i
            With cell.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .ColorIndex = i
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```